# Logitech company ghosting me after agreed return of product

Tags: consumer-protection

Recently I’ve found myself in an interesting situation with the Logitech company. After working with members of their support team, we agreed that I could return my Logitech products to them for a refund. So I boxed up my items and shipped them to their shipping address. Well, fast forward a month and a half. Here I am, all Logitech staff are ghosting me, emails and phone calls. They have my items and haven’t issued a refund. On top of this, the items aren’t for recreational use, but used professionally in a work environment. I’m wondering if it’s normal for a company to take off with its consumer’s returned items, and if this is anywhere near enough of a case to take to court? I’ve tried everything short of this extreme. Cost of items total around 500-600 dollars. Not enough that I would seriously consider court, but enough to make me quite aggravated with such a large company. Thanks!

Comment: Look into the small claims court or equivalent wherever you are. Most jurisdictions have a track in their civil court system which is designed to be quick, simple, cheap and avoids the need for lawyers. Writing a formal letter of complaint which makes it clear that you know about this option and will take it is (in my experience) generally enough to get a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, you could take this to court

When you bough the products you entered into some number of contracts with whoever you bought them off (Unlikely to be Logitech). There are no doubt a bunch of consumer warranties, manufacturer's warranties and implied terms such as merchantability and fitness-for-purpose. No doubt these contracts contain dispute resolution clauses and rights to ombudsmen, tribunals etc.

**However, none of that matters**

Its possible that you and/or Logitech had rights and obligations under all of that stuff and, if so, its likely that both you and Logitech didn't fulfill these to the letter (as contract law requires).

*Notwithstanding,* at the end of your negotiations with Logitech, the two of you entered a pretty clear and unambiguous contract - you would send them a bunch of stuff and they would pay you money. This contract is enforceable.

As an aside, I would suggest that you are not being "ghosted" - just that Logitech is slow.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Perhaps (hopefully) you’re correct that they are just slow, but at what point does that cross a line? A couple months? A year? A couple years? Does that amount of time increase the likelihood of winning a case?

Comment: When its no longer "reasonable" - search this site for that term

Comment: Awesome! Looks like I have some things to think about. Thanks so much for the help!